# How to create pure rest api in yii2?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I want to create a pure rest api in yii2. I had google many keywords but haven't got any right. Please suggest me tutorial links or study material  for pure rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the documentation with an implementation suggestion for how to implement REST APIs using Yii2:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html